# Read from txt file and convert to managed disks

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

I've got a list of virtua machines in Azure which I'm trying to convert to managed disks.

I have a list of vm's, I read from the list and export to csv capturing resourcegroupname and vm name, however I seem to get vms from the whole subscription.

Also when I attempt to import the csv, when I run `$comps` it returns the correct information in the csv, however I can't seem to pass them through to the next lines.

CSV format is

ResouceGroupName   Name
RG-01              vm-01
RG-01              vm-02
RG-01              vm-03
RG-01              vm-04

The code I'm trying is

```
Login-AzureRmAccount

$sub = Get-AzureRmSubscription | ogv -PassThru

Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId $sub

$virtualmachines = Get-Content C:\temp\vm.txt | % {

Get-Azurermvm | select ResourceGroupName,Name | export-csv c:\temp\vm.csv -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Append

}

$comps = Import-Csv c:\temp\Vm.csv | 

foreach ($Comp in $comps) 
{

Stop-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroupName -Name $_.Name -Force

ConvertTo-AzureRmVMManagedDisk -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroupName -VMName $_.Name

}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: when I do the below code I get the correct output

Comment: `$comps = Import-Csv c:\temp\vm1.csv |
 ForEach-Object {
          Write-Host $_.ResourceGroupName Name $_.Name
          }`

Comment: You are not using your list from the pipeline it seems.  Try `Get-AzureVM -Name $_`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your issue, you export the virtual machines in a csv file and use it in the foreach code. So, it's unneccesary to use command:

> ```
> $virtualmachines = Get-Content C:\temp\vm.txt | % {
>
> Get-Azurermvm | select ResourceGroupName,Name | export-csv c:\temp\vm.csv -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Append
>
> }
> ```

And your VMs all in a resourcegroup, you can get them with ResourceGroupName directly.

For the pipeline in foreach, it's unneccesary. You can use the following code that I make a little change with your code and it works well.

```
Login-AzureRmAccount

$sub = Get-AzureRmSubscription | ogv -PassThru

Select-AzureRmSubscription -Subscription $sub

Get-Azurermvm –ResourceGroupName RG-01 | select ResourceGroupName,Name | export-csv c:\temp\vm.csv -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Append

$comps = Import-Csv c:\temp\Vm.csv 

foreach ($Comp in $comps)
{

Stop-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $Comp.ResourceGroupName -Name $Comp.Name -Force

ConvertTo-AzureRmVMManagedDisk -ResourceGroupName $Comp.ResourceGroupName -VMName $Comp.Name

}
```

This is the screenshot of my result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Charles, That's great, only thing is I gave a bad example, the vm's spread across multiple resource groups, which is why I'm getting the resource group for each one from the text file which consists of just hostnames.

Comment: Can you show me how to use a loop from a list of vm's to get resourcegroupname and vmname. like `$virtualmachines = Get-Content C:\temp\vm.txt | % {

Get-Azurermvm | select ResourceGroupName,Name | export-csv c:\temp\vm.csv -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Append

}` Thanks again for all your help :)

Comment: If you want to filter vms in different ResourceGroup, are there vms or ResourceGroups have the similar tag or name so that we can filter them. If not, there will be not a way to filter them.

Comment: Thanks Charles, I was thinking more like get-content list of vms from text file then get-azurermvm and foreach vm get vmname and resourcegroup .. hope that makes sense

Comment: If you want to list vms into a text file. You can use the command "Get-Azurermvm –ResourceGroupName RG-01 | select ResourceGroupName,Name | export-csv c:\temp\vm.csv -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Append | get-content c:\temp\vm.txt"